# how to organize the huge chunk of jquery & ajax code emerging when using web api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web Api, and I have a controller class for each entity. For the main page in my application, however, I need to do some stuff with most of the entities. I am using jQuery & Ajax to make calls to the relevant controller class. This has created already ~400 lines of code, and it may go up to ~1000. For example, I need to write a jquery script to loop through the returned items, and build a table to list the items properly in my page.

To organize it better, I am thinking about moving the jquery code for different entities to separate *.js files. I wonder if there is a better way of doing this. What is the best (but not very complicated) method for this?

**UPDATE**
Here is an example of one of the lengthy jquery ajax functions:

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Functions -- Retriving posts and then displaying 
    function LoadPostsByDiscussionWall(currDiscussionWallId) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/post/GetPostsByDiscussionWall?dwId=' + currDiscussionWallId,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

                var posts = response["$values"];
                DisplayPosts(posts);

            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }

    function DisplayPosts(posts) {
        if (posts.length) {

            $('#div_ListOfPosts').html('');
            $.each(posts, function (index, post) {
                var photo = ''; var displayname = 'Anonymous';
                if (post.IsAnonymous == true) {
                    if (post.Person.AnonymousPhoto.length)
                        photo = post.Person.AnonymousPhoto;
                    if (post.Person.AnonymousName.length)
                        displayname = post.Person.AnonymousName;
                } else {
                    if (post.Person.ProfilePhoto.length)
                        photo = post.Person.ProfilePhoto;
                    displayname = post.Person.FirstName + ' ' + post.Person.LastName;
                }

                var curruserid = $("#hdn_currUserId").val();
                var displayDeleteButton = "";
                if (curruserid === post.Person.Id)
                    var displayDeleteButton = '<a href="#" style="float:right;" data-postid=' + post.PostId + ' class="small text-muted">'
                          + '<span class="small glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>';

                var p = '<div>';

                p = p + '<img style="height:37px;float:left;" src=' + photo.replace('~', '') + ' />'
                      + '<div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">'
                      + displayname
                      + "<br/><span class='small text-muted'>" + post.DatePosted + "</span>"
                      + '</div>'
                      + displayDeleteButton
                      + '</div>';

                p = p + '<div style="float:right;width:100%;margin-top:3px;"><a href="#" data-postid="'
                      + post.PostId
                      + '" class="text-primary postitem" style="font-family:arial;">'
                      + post.Title + "</a>";

                var postContent = post.Content;

                if (post.Content.length > 180) {
                    postContent = post.Content.substring(0, 180) + '...';
                }

                p = p + '<br/><p style="margin-top:3px;padding-bottom:7px;border-bottom:solid 1px #ebebeb;font-family:arial;" class="small">'
                      + postContent + "</p></div>";

                $('#div_ListOfPosts').append(p);

            });
        } else {
            $("#div_ListOfPosts").html("No posts were found. Select another discussion wall.");
        }

    }
    //END Functions -- Retriving posts and then displaying 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Do you need a controller per entity?

Comment: This comment: `To organize it better, I am thinking about moving the jquery code for different entities to separate *.js files. I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.` and.. `This has created already ~400 lines of code, and it may go up to ~1000.` leads me to believe that your 1-1 entity-controller design paradigm is causing you to write extraneous jquery and that you are interested in opinions on potentially "better" ways of going about things. If that's incorrect then the answer to your question is just put the jquery in separate files when you want to reuse the code elsewhere.

Comment: Actually the reason for so many lines of jquery code is my effort to create views to display data and manage it.  Let's say I have a simple ajax call to retrieve the list of items (from the web api controller). Then, within the ajax call I have many lines to build the div (or table) to display the list of items properly. I guess this is fine, right?

Comment: I see - if the bulk of the jquery comes from building / updating lists, tables, or other elements, it might be best to move *that* logic into a custom [jquery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) or maybe use a tool like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). Can you post one of your `ajax` calls?

Comment: thank you! I just added an example to the original question.

Comment: I also would recommend taking a few moments to look at knockout.js.  Knockout will give you a lot of 'leverage' in terms of eliminating all or most of that markup-composition code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code re-usability is key.

For your specific purpose, I would look into creating a custom [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), or maybe even a [jQuery UI - Custom Widget Factory](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/).

In a blog, for example, there may be many different locations you want to return a user's `posts` - not just on their `home` or `main` page. You might want to make the `post` look differently in different areas of the site.

You can use a custom jQuery plugin function to build your `post` entity, and to accept "settings/options" as parameters. This way you have your default `post` entity "widget" but can also change the look and feel without having to re-write lines of code.

Here is an example snippet using `$.extend ()` - but it's not far removed from the practice of creating a custom plugin.

```js
$(function() {

  var tar = $('#parent');

  tar.createPost(); // default "Post"

  // settings for a new post
  var settings = {
    "postWidth": "400px",
    "postContent": "Here's a new post!",
    "postBgColor": "yellow",
    "postData": "foo",
    "postTitle": "Oh no! Not another Post!",
    "postTitleBgColor": "pink"
  };

  tar.createPost(settings);

});



//---------------------------------------------------

// using extend() as an example
// you probably want to author your own plugin

$.fn.extend({

  // o = options
  createPost: function(o) {

    // d = defaults
    var d = {
      postContent: "No post content found! :(",
      postData: "na",
      postHeight: "100%",
      postWidth: "100%",
      postBgColor: "#d2d2d2",
      postTitleWidth: "100%",
      postTitleBgColor: "#fff",
      postTitleBorder: "solid 2px #ebebeb",
      postTitle: "NA",
      postTitleLink: "#",
      postContentFont: "Arial"
    };

    o = $.extend(d, o);

    // Set your function
    this.each(function() {

      // Post and post title elements

      var post = $('<div>');
      var postTitle = $('<a>');
      var postContent = $('<p>');

      // Build components

      post.attr("data-postid", o.postData);
      post.css({
        "height": o.postHeight,
        "width": o.postWidth,
        "background-color": o.postBgColor,
        "margin-top": "15px",
        "border": "dashed 2px lightblue"
      });

      postTitle.attr("href", o.postTitleLink);
      postTitle.text(o.postTitle);
      postTitle.css({
        "display": "inline-block",
        "background-color": o.postTitleBgColor,
        "border": o.postTitleBorder,
        "width": o.postTitleWidth
      });

      postContent.css({
        "font": o.postContentFont
      });

      postContent.html(o.postContent);

      post.append(postTitle);
      post.append(postContent);

      post.appendTo(this);

    });

    return this;

  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I appreciate it. I wonder why you did recommend this approach over KnockoutJS. I am planning to learn these when I get a time but which one would be relatively more advantageous?

Comment: I just wanted to provide you with a *very basic* example. You could certainly accomplish the same goal using knockout or another library altogether. In fact, creating [knockout components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) might be a great fit for your project. The jQuery code is slightly more transparent - that's the only reason I chose it for the example.